# Are there pre-existing and widely used measures for the level of "hierarchy" in a data set?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

Learning about hierarchical clustering, I was wondering if there is a commonly used measure for the amount of hierarchy in a data set?

What I mean is: If the data points are all uncorrelated normal random variables with the same mean and std, clearly there is no hierarchy and thus a hierarchy measure should be 0, or close to 0.

If, on the other hand, there is a strong hierarchical relationship going down many levels, then the measure should be 1 (normalized) or something else far from 0.

EDIT: I should add that I can quite readily come up with a number of ways to approach this question, but wanted to figure out if there's already a widely-used / accepted / standard approach to this, and somehow googling for "hierarchy measure" or something along those lines doesn't yield useful results.

Comment: I'd rather design.a measure to return the number of levels, i.e. 1 for uniform data. But I don't know any such measure, and by experience I'd say they will be quite unreliable.

Comment: Furthermore, a normal distribution *does* look like a hierarchical result, compared to a uniform distribution. So 0=uniform, 1=normal?

Comment: Sounds cool. What are you're approaches to this measure?

Comment: I guess one idea would be to do some hierarchical clustering, then see compare intra-cluster to inter-cluster covariances.

Comment: Well, there's a bunch of measures for internal validation of (flat) clustering. Things like silhouette coefficient, basically, questions like how sharply defined the clusters are. One could look at the average silhouette coefficient at each level of the clustering tree, maybe.

Comment: I suspect such metrics will be data-dependent.  Data with low or high entropy will be easy to recognize, but anything in between will be hard to interpret.

Comment: So I realize that there's a bunch of cluster validation measures such as the silhouette coefficient, etc, for "flat" clustering, but really not all that much for hierarchical clustering

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't heard back with any definite answer, so I thought I'd respond with what I ended up using:

I take my data set for which I want to check the level of hierarchy, and I compute a linkage matrix for it (using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`) from the scipy clustering package.

This gives me a clustering tree expressed in that linkage matrix, and for that tree I compute the **cophenetic correlation coefficient**.

This coefficient measures the correlation between the distance of two elements and the height of the node in the clustering tree (dendrogram) at which the two elements first get joined together.

If you have a high coefficient (close to 1), that means elements that are close together meet early during the agglomerative clustering, and elements that are far apart meet later.

Now, there's a bunch of knobs you can turn, such as what metric to use, and what sort of linkage (single, complete, ward, ...), but I found that it works okay for a ballpark estimate of "yup, this data set has lots of hierarchy and, nope, this data set doesn't".

Early experiments with the silhouette coefficient, btw, proved utterly disappointing.